# How to initialize over a 100 QLabel in an efficient way

Tags: c++, qt

I want to have the ability to update over 100 labels, so I was going to put them in an array like this:

```
voltage_label_array[0] = this->ui->Voltage_0;
voltage_label_array[1] = this->ui->Voltage_1;
voltage_label_array[...] = this->ui->Voltage_2;
voltage_label_array[...n] = this->ui->Voltage_n;
```

and then have this method

```
void MainWindow::updateValue(int i, int voltage){
    voltage_label_array[i]->setText(QString::number(voltage));
}
```

but having 100 lines to set this up seems like a bad idea. Is there a way I can initialize a `QLabel` array inside a for loop or something?

Comment: Not if they're all separate variables. Maybe there's a way to make Qt's UI compiler put them in an array, or maybe you can use a QListWidget or QTableWidget for example instead.

Comment: You might consider constructing your GUI programmatically (e.g. with "new QLabel" inside a for loop, with a QBoxLayout object doing the layout) rather than using the GUI editor program.  That would be quicker than manually constructing 100+ widgets in the editor, and also easier to maintain/update in the future.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do this, something is horribly wrong with your design. But it is possible.

Assuming your labels are named `Voltage_0` to `Voltage_99`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    auto ptr = this->findChild<QLabel*>(QString("Voltage_%1").arg(i));
    voltage_label_array[i] = ptr;
}
```

This "solution" uses Qt's runtime reflection and carries the expected performance penalties.

But if you need to display several similar values, look up [`QListWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html) and similar classes.

Comment: The look-up should be done right after `setupUi(this)` call in the widget's constructor, finding children of the correct parent widget, and then there won't be any performance penalty to speak of. Although it'd be much simpler to create the child widgets in a loop instead of putting them in a `.ui` file. Of course using a view widget (`QListWidget` or `QListView`) would be much better.